# Scrapy. How to send item to close_spider method in pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy

I yield and process many items and in some cases, I update the tracking sheet. This tracking contains several attributes, including country, all these attributes come from the item. All these operations are going in the pipeline. After the spider is closed I have to send this tracking to responsible people by country. But I can't send the item to the method where I catch a closing spider

To catch this moment I use this:

```
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    temp = cls()
    crawler.signals.connect(temp.customize_close_spider, signal=signals.spider_closed)
    return temp

def customize_close_spider(self, **kwargs):
    reason = kwargs.get("reason") 
    spider = kwargs.get("spider")
    if reason == "finished":
        #some action
```

I can send the item neither to from_crawler nor customize_close_spider.
I need it in order to get the country attribute from the item.

Maybe there is another way to send a signal, for example, to another method that I can call from the tracking method

Answer (score 0):

The spider_closed method is only executed once, at the end of the scraping.
If you need to execute something for every item, you can use the process_item method (which is executed for every item).

In case you need to wait until all items have been scraped, you can write all items to a file ([doc](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#write-items-to-a-json-file)), and read from this file in spider_closed.

Comment: Hi Wim, thank you, but the problem is that I need to send the item to close_spider as a parameter in order to get some item attribute to store the file in the correct folder (one of the item attributes is folder name), but close_spider doesn't accept anything except (self, spider)

Comment: that won't be possible (the spider closed is only executed once, it's not executed for every scraped item). If this attribute is the same across all items, you can use a spider attribute instead.

Comment: That is useful, thank you, but how can I access the spider attribute in the pipeline?

Comment: spider.attribute_name